# c# richtextbox outofmemory

Tags: c#, size, richtextbox, out-of-memory

I have written an app that reads incoming chat(somewhat like an instant messenger), formats it and inserts it into a richtextbox.  If you leave the program running long enough you will get an out of memory error.  After looking at my code i think this is because i am never trimming the richtextbox.  The problem that i'm running into is i don't want to call clear() because i don't want the visible text to disappear.  I was thinking maybe i should keep a List with a max size of somthing like 200 lines.  This List would keep the most recent chat.  If the chat log grows to big, call clear and reinsert the last 200 lines.  However, before i implement this thought i would ask if anyone knows of a better solution.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The MaxLength property is probably the closest to setting anything to make the control manage the string.  But, it is probably a poor choice.  So, basically, managing it yourself looks like the best way to go.

Comment: Really? You're running out of memory just for chat? Are your users sending chats by the megabyte?!

Comment: That is what i thought at first too, doesn't happen right away, depends on how much memory you have.  For me my app had to be open for a couple days, but one of my friends that only has 1 gig memory says his would crash within 8 hours with out of memory exception.  Since i have made the change it seems to be working properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably do the following:

1. Catch the `RichTextBox.TextChanged` event
2. In the handler, check the number of lines (`RichTextBox.Lines.Length`)
3. If this exceeds your maximum, remove the first.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the accepted answer, I wanted to provide a code example to show some clarification:

```
private void rtbChatWindow_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int maxLines = 200;

    if (rtbChatWindow.Lines.Length > maxLines)
    {
         string s = rtbChatWindow.Lines.First();
         rtbChatWindow.Text = rtbChatWindow.Text.Remove(0, s.Length).Trim();
    }
}
```

Make sure you call Trim() after you remove the text otherwise the first line of text becomes blank space which causes this to not work.