# Rich Text Box - Text Assignment causes OutofMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I have a program that reads a NTEXT column in SQL Server and displays the output in a rich text box. For one of the values it is throwing up an `OutofMemoryException`.

I read the column using a `SqlDataAdapter` and then append the contents of the column to a `stringBuilder`. I am getting the exception with the following line of code.

```
rtbEventDesc.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

The message displayed is:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

How do I go around this problem? The column size for this particular row is 9 MB, which isn't that much.

Comment: 9MB is quite much... This actually is beyond the scope of a normal stack-based object. Have you checked if the object is still valid, before assigning it to the textbox?

Comment: this might probably be your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642786/c-sharp-richtextbox-outofmemory

Comment: @Yogendra That is not my case. I need to display the entire contents of the column. Then the user can choose to do what she wants.

Comment: Is this throwing on the assignment or on the ToString()? Can you split the code in two and see which one is throwing?

Comment: @SimonMourier I have progressed a bit with my code and I am sure that the ToString() call is working. It fails when I make the assignment to the Text property of the rich text box.

Comment: It probably means you process is using a lot of memory, beyond that simple line you show, because with a brand new X86 WindowsFormsApplication I can successfully put a string of length 214748364 (which is int.Max / 10) without a throw into a richtextbox.

Comment: Try String rtbText = stringBuilder.ToString();  Debug.WriteLine(rtbText.Lenghth.ToString())  to get a total size.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is dumping the coumn to a temporary file and then reading the file using the following:

```
rtbEventDesc.LoadFile(tmpFileName);
```

Hope it helps.

---

**EDIT**

In the case that you cannot use a file to save the file, maybe you can use a memory stream:

```
Byte[] text = GetByteArrayFromSqlAdapter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   ms.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
   rtbEventDesc.LoadFile(ms, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
```

---

**EDIT II**

It seems that the RichTextboxControl is not good enough loading 9Mb file, it doesn't perform better and the main application gets stuck and showing a (Not Responding) message in the Window title.

There are two options here:

1. If the load time ends in a reasonable time, use a BackgroundWorker or any other async mechanism to Load the file, giving feedback to the user while loading.
2. Use other textbox that performs better. I recommend you to use [Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) or [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit)

Comment: Hi Daniel, That's what I intended to do, but this code is running inside an assembly on a server where I may or may not have the necessary privileges to write to a file. Is there something that can be done with memory streams instead? I am currently exploring that option.

Comment: You can use a MemoryStream, but I didn't tested it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am attempting this with the code you have posted. The particular form is now showing a (Not Responding) in the title bar.

Comment: Oh I see, the time loading the file is big, it seems that the RichTextbox does not perform fine with a big text. You have two options: 1) Use a BackgroundWorker or any other async mechanism to Load the file, or search for other textbox that performs better. I recommend you to use Scincilla.NET or AvalonEdit.